# Analyse inequality $1+1.7x^2 <e^x$ and $1+1.7x^2 > e^x$, Intersection of functions

Tags: calculus, inequality

I came acros this post here: [Proof of $1+x\leq e^x$ for all x?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2383019/proof-of-1x-leq-ex-for-all-x)
To sum it up: One could create a function f-g then find the Minimum of this difference function, what led to the argument that there is only one intersection.

If you adjust the left Funktion to b) 1+1.7x^2. How would one analyse in inequality.  Because the solution if with difference function and the derivative does not work anymore. (No approximation, no newton please, I know one could approximate the intersections with newton).

Heres a picture, there are 3 intersection points.

[image: Imgur]

There are 4 areas. And one the  the intersection points x=0 is obvious. But   the others two are not. In each of the "enclosed" areas the inequality sign flips. 
How to prove the inequality in each of these areas, with out the approximation.

I have added a picture. Maybe it could be reduced to solve $e^x=1+1.7x^2$

Answer (score 1):

Considering the function $$f(x)=1+\frac{17}{10} x^2-e^x$$ $$f'(x)=\frac{17 }{5}x-e^x$$ $$f''(x)=\frac{17 }{5}-e^x$$ The first derivative cancels at $$x_1=-W\left(-\frac{5}{17}\right)\qquad \text{and} \qquad x_2=-W_{-1}\left(-\frac{5}{17}\right)$$ where appears [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

So, starting from $x=0$, the derivative is negative when $0\leq x \lt x_1$ and when $x_2 \lt x \lt \infty$. There is a maximum and a minimum for $f(x)$ $$f(x_1)=1+\frac{17}{5} W\left(-\frac{5}{17}\right)+\frac{17}{10}
   W\left(-\frac{5}{17}\right)^2$$ $$f(x_2)=1+\frac{17}{5} W_{-1}\left(-\frac{5}{17}\right)+\frac{17}{10}
   W_{-1}\left(-\frac{5}{17}\right)^2$$ Using the series expansions given in the Wikipedia page, $x_1\approx 0.47$ and  $x_2\approx 1.83$ making $f(x_1)\approx -0.22$ and $f(x_2)\approx 0.46$.

Comment: Why is the Lambert Function needed? What is the connection with the 2nd derivative?

Comment: I am solving $f'(x)=0$ and the solutions are given by Lambert. $f''(x)$ is used for checking if maximum or minimum. Since you did precise *no approximation, no Newton*, this is the best I can do.

Comment: Very interesting! Do you know y any chance a book where I could read something about the Lambert Function? Never heard it before!

Comment: @thetha. It is a very interesting function. Start reading the Wikipedia page. Search on this site to find almost 2000 questions and answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want approximations, you could say, that these two functions intersect in points $x$ satisfying $e^x=1+1.7x^2$, and by looking at the graph you can say, that there are 3 such points and one of them is $x=0$. But I believe, that you don't mean this.

As you refer to question [Proof of $1+x\leq e^x$ for all x?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2383019/proof-of-1x-leq-ex-for-all-x) I assume, that your question is **Proove (or disproove), that $\forall x: e^x \geq (\mathrm{or } \leq) 1+1.7x^2$**

You can solve this in two steps:

1. First create the function $f-g$:
   $$e^x- (1+1.7 x^2) = x-1.2x^2 + \frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}+\ldots = x(1-1.2x+ \frac{x^2}{6}+\frac{x^3}{24}+\ldots)$$
   and notice, that it have at least one root at $x=0$. If $\forall x: e^x \geq (\mathrm{or } \leq) 1+1.7x^2$, then in all roots (in particular $x=0$) there are extremes.
2. Create the derivative function $h=(f-g)'$:
   $$h(x)=e^x- 3.4x = 1 - 2.4x+\frac{x^2}{2}+ \frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}+\ldots $$
   Of course $h(0)=1\neq 0$, so there is no extremum in $x=0$.

Thus the statement $\forall x: e^x \geq (\mathrm{or } \leq) 1+1.7x^2$ is not true.

Comment: I have posted a picture of the problem, there are 4 areas, where the > sign  is flipping. How to show the inequality(with the correct sign) in each of the areas, with out the approximation. I have updated the problem. It is not a proove or disaproove problem.