# Prove that $a^n \gt \frac{(n \ln(a))^m}{m!}$ without using taylor series.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, exponential-function

Prove that $a^n = e^{n \ln(a)} \gt \dfrac{(n \ln(a))^m}{m!}$ for all $m\in \mathbb{N}$ and $a>1$ without using taylor series/calculus.

I am trying methods that use binomial theorem but I can't get far. I tried induction on $m$. For $m=1$, we have $e^{n\ln(a)}>n\ln(a)$, which is true since $e^x\geq 1+x>x.$ Suppose the proposition is true for $m=t,$ then we have $e^{n\ln(a)}>\dfrac{{(n\ln(a))^t}}{t!}.$ Then in order to prove $m=t+1$ is true we must could show that $e^{n\ln(a)}>\dfrac{e^{n\ln(a)}n\ln(a)}{t+1}.$ But after this step I am stuck. Any hints/ideas will be much appreciated.

Comment: May I wrong, but it's trivial!

Comment: @MyGlasses what do you mean?

Comment: No Taylor Series!

Comment: Could you please post your proof?

Comment: If you use $e^x > 1+x$ there is no great leap to $e^x>\sum_{k=0}^m x^k/k!$

Comment: It's in general not easy to avoid calculus, since the definition of the various functions involved is always done with calculus. How do you define $e$, $\ln$, etc. without calculus?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews you may have a look to the answers below

Comment: @GuyFsone Most of them use calculus. Mine doesn't, but is still stuck making an $\epsilon$ argument, and using that $e^x>1+x$ for $x>0$. To prove that latter you'll need some definition of $e^x$, say, as a limit of $(1+x/n)^n$ or a power series, which is again calculus.

Comment: If you don't to use calculus what  else will you use. My answer is just induction.

Comment: You use derivatives. That's calculus. My point is that the conditions of the question was: "without using Taylor series/calculus." It's not clear what you are disagreeing with, then. @GuyFsone

Comment: The OP banned only Taylor series in your post. Also this question is about Calculus as well.

Comment: If you only read the title, sure. Did you read the question? @GuyFsone Quote: "without using taylor series/calculus." You still are arguing against something that I said was blatantly true - all of the answers so far use calculus, and it would be difficult to not use calculus. When I said this, you pointed me to the answers below, all of which use calculus. So I said it would be difficult to not use calculus. 
You basically are agreeing with me while acting as if you are correcting me.

Answer (score 3):

Let prove by induction that 
$$e^x >\frac{x^m}{m!} ~~~, \forall ~~m~~ x>0$$

1. for $n=0$, we have  $e^x > 1 =\frac{x^)0}{0!}$
2. Asumme that $e^x  >\frac{x^m}{m!} ~~~,  x>0$

consider $$(0,\infty)\ni x\mapsto f(x) = e^x  -\frac{x^{m+1}}{(m+1)!}$$

**Then by Assumption we have** $$  f'(x) = e^x  -\frac{x^{m}}{m!}>0$$
that is $f$ **is strictly increasing on $(0,\infty)$ therefore,**

$$ 0=f(0)<f(x) =e^x  -\frac{x^{m+1}}{(m+1)!}$$

hence for all $m$
we have $$e^x  -\frac{x^{m}}{m!}>0$$

> In particular $a>1$ then, taking, $x= n\ln a>0$ one gets
>   $$a^n = e^{n \ln(a)} \gt \dfrac{(n \ln(a))^m}{m!}$$

Answer (score 3):

Prove with induction. $P(n): e^x>\dfrac{x^n}{n!}$ then $P(0): e^x>1$ is trivial. With assumption $P(m): e^x>\dfrac{x^m}{m!}$ be true, then 
$$\int_0^x e^x>\int_0^x \dfrac{x^m}{m!}=\dfrac{x^{m+1}}{(m+1)!}$$
shows  $P(m+1)$ is true.

Comment: This is an incredibly slick answer.

Comment: But it uses calculus!

Comment: Nice, but you shouldn't use $x$ in two ways like that. It should be $\int_0^x e^t\,dt$.

Comment: Thanks. yes. Can make confusion for some people!

Comment: Sorry, but if writing things correctly creates confusion, then they need to be confused so that they learn to understand things written correctly.

Comment: How those the last line holds true? While passing integral on both side the inequality is no more strict but rather large.

Comment: Why is this inequality strick?$ \int_0^x e^x>\int_0^x \dfrac{x^m}{m!}$

Comment: If $f(x)>g(x)$ are continuous on $[a,b]$, then $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)>\int_a^{b} g(x)$. You don't actually need strict inequality, though, because the left side is $e^x-1$ and the right side is $\frac{x^{m+1}}{(m+1)!}$ so you get $$e^x>e^x-1\geq \frac{x^{m+1}}{(m+1)!}.$$

Answer (score 3):

We assume two results:

1. $e^x>1+x$ for $x>0$.
2. $(e^y)^n= e^{yn}$ for an real $y$ and positive integer $n$.

and prove:

> **Theorem**: If $x>0$ and $m$ a non-negative integer, then $e^x>\frac{x^m}{m!}.$

Assumption (1) implies this result for $m=0,1.$

Given any $x>0$, and any integer $k>m$,  (1) means $e^{x/k}\geq 1+\frac{x}{k}$ and thus, by $(2)$:

$$e^x = (e^{x/k})^k>\left(1+\frac{x}{k}\right)^k\geq 1+\binom{k}{m}\frac{x^m}{k^m}$$

By the binomial theorem.

Now $$\frac{1}{k^m}\binom{k}{m}=\frac{(1-1/k)(1-2/k)\cdots(1-(m-1)/k)}{m!}>\frac{(1-m/k)^m}{m!}$$

Now you need to show that if you pick $\epsilon>0$ you can find $k$ so that:

$$(1-m/k)^m>1-\epsilon$$

(We will assume $\epsilon<1$.)

Then we want $1-\frac{m}{k}>(1-\epsilon)^{1/m}$ or

$$k>m\left(1-(1-\epsilon)^{1/m}\right)^{-1}$$

So this means:

$$e^x>1+\frac{1-\epsilon}{m!}x^m=\frac{x^m}{m!}+\left(1-\frac{x^m}{m!}\epsilon\right)$$ for any $\epsilon>0$.

But then pick $\epsilon <\min\left(1,\frac{m!}{x^m}\right)$ so we get:

$$e^x>\frac{x^m}{m!}$$

---

None of these steps used calculus, but (1) and (2) depend on our definition of $e$ (or of $e^x$).

If you define $e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac xn\right)^n$ then you get (1) and (2) pretty easily, but you'd have to prove that this limit exists.

If you define $e^x$ in terms of the power series expansion, then you get the theorem much more directly.

Other ways to define $e^x$ or $e$ are with integrals (definition of natural logarithm) or derivatives, which are calculus. I guess you could "hide" the calculus by defining natural log as a limit of the Reimann sums, and brute force from there.

Comment: This is really avoiding calculus (derivatives, integrals so to speak). It uses two fundamental ideas : $e^{x} \geq 1+x,e^{x+y}=e^{x}e^{y}$. It is interesting to note that these two properties characterize the exponential function. +1

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2383082/72031

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yeah. Technically, I don't use the case $x<0$, so $c^x$ satisfies this inequality for any $c\geq e$. While $e^x> 1+x$ for all $x\neq 0$, the general inequality is not true. For $x=-2, m=2$ you get $e^{-2}<\frac{(-2)^2}{2!}=2$, for example.