# Why is $a=e$ the smallest number such that $a^x\ge 1+x$ for all $x$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality, exponential-function, exponentiation

Calculus book:

> Find all numbers $a$ such that $\forall x, a^x \ge 1+x$

I immediately thought of the inequality $e^x\ge 1+x$ and guessed that the answer was any number $a$ in $[e,\infty)$. After playing around with a graphing app I can see this is definitely true, although I can't explain why.

Why is $e$ specifically the smallest number such that the inequality holds? To my untrained eye, a quick scan of the equation does not give rise to anything involving the constant $e$. Maybe because $1+x$ is only a tangent to the equation $a^x$ when $a=e$? Thanks.

Comment: $e^x$ is not the smallest number $\ge 1+x$.

Comment: Have you worded your question right? Are you looking for smallest $a$ such that $a^x \geq 1+x , \, \forall x$?

Comment: @baharampuri Actually, I'm looking for all numbers $a$ that satisfy that constraint for all $x$. The answer is probably in the form of an interval.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Judging from your five upvotes on that comment, I've made a mistake in my question. But the two answers I have (including yours) confirm $e$ is the smallest number. Have I made a mathematical typo? You seem to be understanding my question.

Comment: @LugGian: I've now fixed the title so it actually fits your question.

Comment: @celtschk Thanks. What was wrong with it? In particular, why did Lord Shark say $e^x$ is not the smallest number (if you don't mind me asking)?

Comment: As originally formulated, you asked about the number $e^x$. But the number $e^x$ is not for all $x$ the smallest number $\ge 1+x$; for example, for $x=1$, $e^x=e>1+x=2$, but obviously the smallest number $\ge 2$ is $2$. With the reformulated title, the question asks no longer about the size of $e^x$, but about the size of the base $a$ of the exponential $a^x$, which must be at least $e$ so that the inequality is fulfilled for all $x$.

Comment: See this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2383082/72031

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $0<a<e$. The derivative of $f(x)=a^x$ is $f'(x)=(\ln a )a^x$.
In particular $f'(0)=\ln a<1$. Since $\ln a<(1+\ln a)/2<1$,
there is a $\delta>0$ such that
$$f(x)<f(0)+\frac{1+\ln a}2x<1+x$$
when $1<x<1+\delta$.

Comment: OP speaking: You said $f'(1)=\ln a$, but I think you mean $f'(0)$?

Answer (score 3):

Note that $e^x$ has taylor series:
$$e^x = 1+x+x^2/2!+\dots$$
We can rewrite $a^x = e^{x\ln a}$, then this has taylor series:
$$a^x = e^{x\ln a} = 1+x\ln a+ x^2(\ln a)^2/2!+\dots$$
Now, if we want $a^x\geq 1+x$, this means:
$$1+x\ln a+x^2(\ln a)^2/2!+\dots \geq 1+x\implies x(\ln a-1)+x^2(\ln a)^2/2!+\dots\geq 0$$
All of the coefficients of the taylor polynomial on the left are positive if and only if $\ln a-1\geq 0\implies \ln a \geq 1$, so if $a\geq e$.

If $a<e$, then for $x>0$ the inequality won't hold.  I'm guessing it wouldn't be too bad to compute specific intervals where the inequality fails, but I'll omit this for now.